# Query hdfs with Spark Sql

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv file in hdfs, how can I query this file with spark SQL? For example I would like to make a select request on special columns and get the result to be stored again to the Hadoop distributed file system

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve by creating Dataframe.

```
val dataFrame = spark.sparkContext
  .textFile("examples/src/main/resources/people.csv")
  .map(_.split(","))
  .map(attributes => Person(attributes(0), attributes(1).trim.toInt))
  .toDF()

dataFrame.sql("<sql query>");
```

Comment: You have SparkSession, so it's Spark 2.0. Why you are not using built-in CSV parser?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should create a SparkSession. An example is [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#starting-point-sparksession).
2. Load a CSV file: `val df = sparkSession.read.csv("path to your file in HDFS")`.
3. Perform your select operation: `val df2 = df.select("field1", "field2")`.
4. Write the results back: `df2.write.csv("path to a new file in HDFS")`